# Cant grab and manipulate HTML elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let button = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
button.value = 8;

//button.textCont = 'X'; --- DOESN'T WORK.
//button.innerHTML = 'X'; --- DOESN'T WORK.
```

```css
body {
 background-color: coral;
}

h1 {
 font-family: 'monospace';
 text-align: center;
}

button {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: relative;
 left: 35px;
 top: 35px;
 background-color: coral;
 border: none;
 margin: 4px;
}


.game-box {
 background-color: black;
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 border-radius: 10%;
 margin: auto;

}

.shave-left-top {
 border-top-left-radius: 10%;
}

.shave-right-top {
 border-top-right-radius: 10%;
}

.shave-left-bottom {
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10%;
}

.shave-right-bottom {
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>javaScript Tic Tac Toe</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body class="wrapper">
 <h1>javascript Tic Tac Toe</h1>

 <div class="game-box">
  <div class="row-1">
   <button class="shave-left-top"></button> 
   <button ></button> 
   <button class="shave-right-top"></button> 
  </div>

  <div class="row-2">
   <button></button> 
   <button></button> 
   <button></button> 
  </div>

  <div class="row-3">
   <button class="shave-left-bottom"></button> 
   <button></button> 
   <button class="shave-right-bottom"></button> 
  </div>

 </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hey guys, don't know what's going on. Can't seem to grab and and change the button value with my JS, I do have an error in my console: SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80700013, http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/9/F/B9FF9327-7A72-4165-BF91-9B7EEB6C579B/DeviceList.json

I download this but it does nothing, then the error shows up again later. Any help on this one? I had the same problem making a JS calculator. I even posted it up, but can't find an answer. I'm using Sublime 3 and edge for my browser if that helps. Thanks.

Comment: document.getElement_s_ “elements” is the key part. It will return an HTMLCollection, which is similar to an array. Just specify an index in the collection and go wild.

Comment: Examine the variable `button` in the debugger (do you know what that is?). What is it? Does it have a `value` property?

Answer (score 2):

```
let button = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
```

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array of all tags with the name button.

To remedy this, either change the first element at the first index of the array if you only have one button

```
   button[0].value = 8;
   button[0].textCont = 'X';
   button[0].innerHTML = 'X';
```

or iterate through the array and change the attributes of each individual button.

```
for(var i = 0; i < button.length; i++)
{
   button[i].value = 8;
   button[i].textCont = 'X';
   button[i].innerHTML = 'X';
}
```